# printing first 27 values in the Fibonacci series

Tags: assembly, masm, fibonacci, irvine32

I am trying to display the first 27 values in the Fibonacci series, in assembly language. I am having a lot of trouble. I am keeping going around in circles so please help me. What I am seeing is not making sense to me.

```
TITLE Fibonacci
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC
mov ebp, 0
mov edx, 1
mov ebx, edx
mov ecx, 27
L1:
mov eax, edx
mov ebp, eax
mov edx, ebx
add ebx, ebp
call DumpRegs
call WriteInt
loop L1
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your program by using code blocks so that it will be possible to read and understand it. Please also beat bit more specific about the part you don't understand and/or you got stuck at, since too broad of a question is less likely to result in the answers you are looking for. Also welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: possible duplicate of [first 27 values in the Fibonacci series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774722/first-27-values-in-the-fibonacci-series)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't try to include the first 2 numbers in your loop. It doesn't pay!

In your code you initialize EBP=0 but this is unneeded. You can do the job even without using EBP altogether.

Here's my minimalistic version for 27 fibonacci numbers:

```
 mov  eax, 1
 call WriteInt
 call WriteInt
 mov  edx, eax
 mov  ecx, 27-2
L1:
 xchg eax, edx
 add  eax, edx
 call WriteInt
 loop L1
```

Do make sure routines like *DumpRegs* and *WriteInt* preserve the registers that you use in your code.

Comment: after I impliment this code must I proceed to display 26 more numbers. I am really confused with assembly

Comment: Why would you display any more numbers? The code written by @user3144770 already outputs 27 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If we use a *less intuitive* setup **we can** display all 27 Fibonacci numbers from a single loop!

```
mov  ecx, 27
mov  eax, 1
cdq             ;EDX becomes 0
L1:
call WriteInt
xchg eax, edx
add  eax, edx
loop L1
```

This solution outputs **1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...** but some authors start the Fibonacci series at **0**. To accomplish that just do 1 separate *WriteInt* before the loop and use a counter of 26.

```
mov  ecx, 26
xor  eax, eax
call WriteInt
inc  eax
cdq             ;EDX becomes 0
L1:
call WriteInt
xchg eax, edx
add  eax, edx
loop L1
```

Now the ouput will look like **0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...**